# Open source alternative to Katalon Studio - test automation solution

Tags: software-testing

I have been using [Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/) for functional test automation for a while now, since it was free and have powerful test automation feature which built on top of selenium.

However the recent license change for the latest Katalon Studio make lots of feature unusable in the free version, so I am looking for an alternative to it.

Product requirement:

1. Free and Open source, so we can contribute and add features when needed

Feature requirements:

1. Able to import and export to selenium
2. Have both GUI and command line interface
3. Record test case just by going to the website, and navigating the sites
4. Parallel test execution
5. Integration with Jenkin

Comment: AlternativeTo only [suggests](https://alternativeto.net/software/katalon-studio/?license=free) Selenium (industry standard - what's wrong with it?) and [UI.Vision RPA](UI.Vision RPA), although that is the successor to Kantu, which was billed as a Selenium IDE. Great question! Upvote and marked as favourite. I hope that you get an answer. If you find a solution, please post and accept your own answer, which will help others who raead thsi question in future. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comment! **Katalon Studio** Record test case just by going to the website which makes it much better to use than **Selenium** which (from my research) is code based only. Also many GUI feature is lacking in Selenium. When have time will look into the UI Vision RPA but seems like it is freemium... Open source is much much preferred. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad that you are happy. BUT, it is always better to learn to code. Recorders will juts click at mouse coordinate X, Y, but what if yu resize the screen?